# Обход XML дерева с сохранением пути до конечного значения в ветке

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, рекурсия

Имеется XML вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно обойти всё дерево и в конце каждой ветки возвращать значение и полный путь до него. Проблема в создании полного пути. Решил заполнять массив ключами, а в конце уже смержить.

```
import xmltodict

xml_keys = []
xml_keys_temp = []


def foo(obj, parent_key=''):
    global xml_keys, xml_keys_temp
    xml_keys.append(parent_key)

    if isinstance(obj, xmltodict.OrderedDict):

        for key in obj.keys():
            xml_keys_temp.append(key)
            foo(obj[key], key)
        xml_keys.clear()

    else:
        print(xml_keys, obj)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('18182.xml') as f:
        xml_file = f.read()
    foo(xmltodict.parse(xml_file))
```

Output:

```
>>> ['', 'Root', 'Data', 'authentication'] true
>>> ['', 'Root', 'Data', 'authentication', 'key'] 1234
>>> ['', 'Root', 'Data', 'authentication', 'key', 'method'] book
>>> ['book', 'id'] 18182
>>> ['book', 'id', 'title'] A Theory of Fun for Game Design
>>> ['book', 'id', 'title', 'is_ebook'] false
>>> ['book', 'id', 'title', 'is_ebook', 'work', 'id'] 19639
>>> ['book', 'id', 'title', 'is_ebook', 'work', 'id', 'books_count'] 16
>>> ['average_rating'] 3.94
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Нужно было создать массив **xml_list** и при каждом рекурсивном вызове передавать его аргументом в следующий вызов, предварительно добавляя в него ключ словаря от предыдущего вызова — **xml_key**. В конце ветки, когда объект |= словарь, создать [временный](http://pythoner.name/documentation/tutorial/classes/namespaces) массив **full_key_list** и добавить в него все элементы переданного массива + ключ.

```
import xmltodict

#Лист с ключами, которые будем передавать дальше
xml_list = []


def foo(obj, xml_key='', xml_list_keys = []):

    # проверяем объект на принадлежность к классу словаря
    if isinstance(obj, xmltodict.OrderedDict):
        # добавляем в лист ключ, по которому этот объект получен
        xml_list.append(xml_key)
        # по всем ключам в объекте делаем тоже самое
        for key in obj.keys():
            # отдаем в функцию новый объект, ключ и список ключей до него
            foo(obj[key], key, xml_list)
    # объект не словарь
    else:
        # временный лист для хранения всех ключей
        full_key_list = []

        for key in xml_list:
            if key:
                full_key_list.append(key)
        # добавляем последний ключ
        full_key_list.append(xml_key)
        print(full_key_list, obj)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('18182.xml') as f:
        xml_file = f.read()
        foo(xmltodict.parse(xml_file))
```

Output:

```
['Root', 'Data', 'authentication'] true
['Root', 'Data', 'key'] 1234
['Root', 'Data', 'method'] book
['Root', 'Data', 'book', 'id'] 18182
['Root', 'Data', 'book', 'title'] A Theory of Fun for Game Design
['Root', 'Data', 'book', 'is_ebook'] false
['Root', 'Data', 'book', 'work', 'id'] 19639
['Root', 'Data', 'book', 'work', 'books_count'] 16
['Root', 'Data', 'book', 'work', 'average_rating'] 3.94
```